# How to draw prefix and postfix binary tree?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, trees

I have drawn these two binary trees.

The ordered set of numbers is [-9, -5, 0, 1, 5, 7, 8, 10, 11]

[image]

The first one is in prefix order and the second is in postfix order, but I'm not sure if my trees are correct? And are they balanced?

Comment: Swap $(10, 11)$ in prefix binary tree.

Comment: @Mithlesh Upadhyay Oh yea! You got my one mistake. So other than the (10, 11), they're correct?